# Code- and Comment-Templates in Domino Designer: how to format template variables?

Tags: lotusscript, domino-designer-eclipse

For a while I've been using code and comment templates in Domino Designer, not only with Java / JavaScript / Xpages etc. but with LotusScript as well.

In my templates I'm using built-in variables like `${date}`, `${author}` or `${user}`. They are putting out the current date in US format as in *Sep 14, 2018*, or (obviously) the first entries from my Domino person doc's fullname or short name fields.
I wonder whether the output can be formatted in some way. Example: 
I'd love to have the current date formatted as **2018-09-14** instead, or use a different entry from ShortName or even a different field.

Would I have to build my own variable to achieve this, or is there some place (well hidden in Domino Designer) where I can modify that logic?

And while I'm at it: where and how could I build my own variables?

Google-ing you find plenty of stuff regarding Eclipse itself but nothing that would be dealing with all that special Domino Designer stuff.

Any hint, examples and/or link to relevant tutorials is more than welcome.